# <picture /> element is not working as expected in Safari browser, while using React

Tags: html, reactjs, image, picturefill

I am facing an issue with "picture" element in React, particularly with safari browser.
Safari is always fetching image from "img" element src along with the image from appropriate "source" element based on media attribute.

This seem to work fine in other browsers(chrome & firefox).

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-tesla-es10w?file=/src/index.js) for the same.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

FYI: I tried with picturefill polyfill too. But no help. So, thought it is something to do with react + safari engine combo.

Comment: it works on safari for me.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, is safari fetching only appropriate <source /> src and not src from "img" tag too?
I am using Safari Version 13.0.4 (15608.4.9.1.3). It is fetching both correct "source"element src and the "img" element src.

Comment: Did you solve this Suresh? I'm also facing the same problem

Comment: In my case the issue occurs when picture elements are generated dynamically using React or Vue, there is no issue if the html is static.

Comment: For more information see https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11357

Answer (score 0):

For what is it worth, I have narrowed my issue with this on Safari:
Seems to work with a vanilla  element but when I have an HTML custom element and create the picture tag within the InnerHTML of a template (document.createElement("template").

I am using Vanilla JS not React but perhaps it is doing something similar under the covers.

I tried with and without specifying a "type" attribute on the  but no effect.

Works fine on Chrome.
Safari version is Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.7)

Comment: Perhaps doesn't sit well in an answer. try to make sure when posting an answer, you are doing so with confidence that it solves the issue. Also using the comment section under the question makes more sense for suggestions and additions

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have also encountered this strange bug on Safari. I was doing `document.createElement("template")` and the `picture` tag was not working.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you forgot `type` attribute of `source` element. It was the problem in my case.

Comment: No, I added `type` for source elements. I attached codesandbox URL in the question.